# ドメインが example.jp なメールアドレスの作り方

Tags: mail

「安全なwebアプリケーションの作り方」という本を勉強しているのですが、実習用のメールアカウントの作り方がわかりません。

> ユーザ名: wasbook
> パスワード: wasbook
> メールアドレス: wasbook@example.jp
> POP3サーバ: example.jp
> SMTPサーバ: example.jp

のメールを作成するようなのですが、@以降がexample.jpのメールアドレスはどうすれば作れるのでしょうか？

Comment: あくまでサンプル用のアドレスであり、適宜読み替えるべきです。

Comment: 著者です。ご愛読に感謝いたします。
上記メールアカウントは、添付のVMには既に作成されています。ご質問の趣旨は、「メールアカウントの作り方」ではなく、メールソフト（Outlook等）の設定の方法ではないでしょうか?

Answer (score 2):

閉じたネットワークで使う場合や、実験用に使用する為のドメインが予約されていて（RFCなどで定義されている）、`example.jp`もそのたぐいです。

`example.jp` ドメインのメールアドレスを作りたいのであれば、完全に閉じた（インターネットに接続しない）ネットワークを構築して その中で DNS サーバーとメールサーバー(POP3, SMTPそれぞれ)を構築する必要があります。

ただ、上記の環境づくりは、勉強としては有用ですが Webアプリケーションには直接は関係ありませんので、ご自身で 有効なメールアドレスを取得して使われるのが良いかも知れません。

テスト用途などで複数のアドレスが必用な場合は、例えば、Gmailではれば `アカウント+xxxx@gmail.com` というように `+` の後ろに好きな文字を加えれば 1つのメールアドレスの エイリアスとして使えます。

(例)
`hoge@gmail.com`
`hoge+foo@gmail.com`
`hoge+test@gmail.com`

注意点としては、テスト用途といえども、実際にメールが飛んでしまいますので、ご自身が管理していない 実在するメールアドレスやドメイン は使わないほうが良いですよ。

Comment: 徳丸浩氏著「[体系的に学ぶ 安全なWebアプリケーションの作り方　脆弱性が生まれる原理と対策の実践](http://www.sbcr.jp/products/4797361193.html)」には、メールサーバーなどが構築済みのVMwareイメージが同梱されており、hostsファイルに`example.jp`のホストを自身のIPアドレスに解決するように記述すれば、DNSサーバーを用意しなくても環境が作れるようになっています。

Comment: Vmwareで閉じたネットワークを構築されてるのですね。ご提示頂いた書籍は存じておりませんが VmwareゲストOS上で `useradd newuser` で `newuser@example.jp` のアドレスが作れるような気がします。出来なければそのゲストの設定等を質問に追記してもらえればコメントできるかもしれません。

Comment: 言葉が不足しており申し訳ありません。"安全なwebアプリケーションの作り方という本を勉強している"とありますので、書籍内の環境構築手順に不明点があるというのが、質問の趣旨のように思えますということです。

Comment: なるほど、質問の前提になるテキストがあるのですね。